# To delete the data of a cell based on aging to keep only aged items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got stuck while working on a report and i would love to have your support on it :
Basically, I have payment IDs with aging,but since they are split across aging buckets, i have doubles

For Example: In Payment ID column, there is a list of payment, part of those payment are doubles since they fall in 2 or more aging categories, what i would like to do is : to find a way how i can remove the doubles and keep only one record with the aged category.
That way i can make a pivot and see the aging of the payment accurately

Aging categories used : 1-30, 31 to 60, 61 to 90, 91 to 180

I am not able to add any photos yet, that would make it easier to understand

Hope i was clear enough
Thanks a lot in advance :)

I have tried remove duplicates, Find function but i did not get the result needed

Comment: Sorry about that i have edited my post, hope its clearer, unfortunately i am not able to add photos which would make it easier to explain,

Comment: FYI, you can upload image to http://imgur.com and link to them, someone with enough reputation can then embed them in your question

Comment: Remove Duplicates should give you the result you want. When the Remove Duplicates box comes up and asks you to select which columns contain duplicates, check the box beside Payment ID only. Leave the other boxes unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerQuery to remove the duplicates.  If your data is already in an Excel Table, click the table and then Data > From Table.

In PowerQuery, click **Remove Rows** in the ribbon and select **Remove Duplicates**.  **Close & Load To...** and choose **Only Create Connection** and tick, **Add this data to the Data Model**.

Now you can create your PivotTable from the Data Model. (Insert > PivotTable, **Use this workbook's Data Model**)